# Why was this question deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion

The deletion policy says:

> "Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may
>   be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators."

I cannot even vote to un-delete this question because it was deleted by a moderator. What reasoning was there for deleting this question, especially without consulting the community?

[image]

Comment: Yes @Blue, I guess it is funny how things work! I've actually tried to un-downvote it several times, but keep getting the message that I can't un-downvote a deleted question. Anyway, deleting it after I'd already spent so much time writing an answer was not nice. If James is now credited with deleting it, does that mean you un-deleted it at some point?

Comment: @Blue: I'm not sure that's how the events took place. I'm quite sure I had downvoted it well before I answered it. I also think you deleted the question almost immediately after I answered it. However, I downvoted this question only after you downvoted my answer to your question with bounty and tried to humiliate me by saying that my contributions were "extremely trivial and obvious".

Comment: I wasn't the one that downvoted or close voted your authorship order question by the way. I only saw the question after you'd already deleted it. I was going to upvote it to neutralize the downvote but couldn't do that since it was deleted. I was going to answer it too.

Comment: How do we move this to chat?

Comment: You may flag the comments as "obselete". Or else flag them for the mods, with a message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84147/discussion-between-user1271772-and-blue).

Comment: Related: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: just to be clear, did you already post an answer to the question? If the problem is the OP deleting his own question thus making your answer disappear as well, you can simply re-ask the same question and self-answer it, thus making your effort not go to waste. The way I see it, as long as the OP *can* delete his/her own question for whatever reason, his/her has the right to do it, no questions asked. If this is instead specifically about the moderator's deleting the question, then, while a bit weird, I don't see how this is important given that the question was deleted by the OP anyway

Comment: @glS: I did post an answer. I can re-ask the question but it won't carry the same weight. I'll look like a "rep-whore" or whatever they call it on Meta. I also can't get points for accepting my own answer.  "as long as the OP can delete his/her own question for whatever reason, his/her has the right to do it, no questions asked." ... considering all the warnings all over the place about deleting questions that already have answers, I think users should be very careful not to delete things, especially when it's out of spite. The user says he deleted the question because there was  -1, but

Comment: a lot of people know that person was also negative voting a lot of my other stuff at the same time. " If this is instead specifically about the moderator's deleting the question, then, while a bit weird, I don't see how this is important given that the question was deleted by the OP anyway" sure, but I can't even vote to undelete the question, because it was deleted by a moderator!

Comment: who called someone self-answering a "rep-whore"??? It is absolutely accepted and encouraged to self-answer questions. I don't get what is the problem with not getting those 15 additional internet points for the accepted answer, especially as you can probably get more by other people upvoting the question (and just to repeat myself, why do you care about a few rep points anyway??).

Comment: @gIS: I have seen the term "rep-whore" used before, it is not a phrase I like, and I also saw a Meta about telling people to stop using that term. However the term exists, and also I felt that way sometimes when I saw some users here answering their own questions (I have done it too, and didn't like doing it, so only did it in certain cases and I always prefer to answer other people's questions rather than my own). Yes the 15 points isn't HUGE, but a bigger point is that this question was deleted and that deletion seems to violate all the guidelines. I also didn't know we can re-port questions

Comment: A moderator deleted the question, should I dare ask it again? I don't know. If you ask the question I'll answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well... It turns out that moderators are people too (honest!) and will occasionally make the odd misclick...

Following a short conversation with the OP of the question (Blue), the question is now reopened and can be found [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4135/23).

(apologies for this and the inconvenience)